# setting the properties of different plots at once in matlab

Tags: matlab, properties, handle, figure

In a m-file, I am plotting 16 different types of plots (not in a loop). Is it possible to set the following properties of all the plots by writing only once:

```
 set(gca,'linewidth',1,'fontsize',12);
 set([xh, yh, th],'fontsize',12);
```

Comment: Are they all in the same figure? There are some things you can do with `linkaxes`. I don't know (but you could try) if you can pass an array of handles to `set`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is yes, which can be easily checked e.g. using this code

```
figure
xh = gca;
figure
yh = gca;

set([xh, yh], 'fontsize', 12, 'linewidth', 1);
```

Note that the 'linewidth' property of an axes applies to the lines that make up the axes, not to any lines plotted into it. If you want to change their properties, you have to either collect the handles of all the line objects, or search for line objects later using

```
lh = findobj(0, 'Type', 'line');
set(lh, 'linewidth', 1)
```

Here '0' refers to the root object, of which all figures are children.

Comment: That's great! I just wanted to suggest to write a little function where you pass all handles and set the settings in a loop. But if it's possible like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can change default plotting parameters:

```
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',1);
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize', 12);
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize', 12);
```

Yes, it is meant to be "LineLine", it's to distinguish it from `DefaultPatchLineWidth`.  Once you change these, it will only affect new figure windows; if you have already created the plots, use the answer given by A. Donda.